# How to insert location using google map in odoo13

Tags: geolocation, odoo

I want to add a button and when click button,google map will display and choose some location.After that insert to this location to char field in form view.How can I do that? Can I get some reference or instruction?

Comment: Refer https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/web_google_maps/..  https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/base_google_map/

Comment: @VishnuVaNnErI. I already known this module. My requirement is open google map and ping location and add this location to char field.